# CSS Responsive- How can I make ZOOM property for responsivness working on iOS devices?

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design, responsiveness, zoom-sdk

I've recently discovered a bug on iOS and I am wondering how should I solve it.

To make things faster, I am using the zoom property of CSS to make the responsive part of my Dota 2 website clone.

On android everything is working as it should be but on iOS everything is messed up. There should be an workaround because the Dota 2 original web application is using zoom from what I know.

I've tried multiple solutions, nothing seems to work.

The meta tags i've tried so far are following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,shrink-to-fit=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 shrink-to-fit=no" />
```

The media queries i've tried for that lists of teams column stacked are:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    zoom: 0.9;
    width: 85%;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    zoom: 0.8;
    width: 99%;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 695px) {
    zoom: 0.7;

    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 595px) {
    zoom: 0.6;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 495px) {
    zoom: 0.5;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
```

The media queries i've tried for tabels grid are:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
    zoom: 0.8;
    width: 100%;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1550px) {
    zoom: 0.8;
    width: 85%;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    zoom: 0.7;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 668px) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
    width: 100%;
  }
```

I've also tried the both media queries with: `text-size-adjust: none;` and still no results.
The grid table doesn't really looks that bad but the other component is really messed up.

> By the way, I didn't use the zoom property on all CSS containers and elements, I just used on the wrapper that wraps the entire component pretty much or on the parent container.

Now I am gonna attach some photos for you to see the diferences.

iOS latest version - iOS iPhone - Safari browser and Chrome
iOS Comparision My site vs Original

[image: iOS Comparision My site vs Original]

Android latest version - Google Chrome browser
Android Comparision My site vs Original

[image: Android Comparision My site vs Original]

As you can see in the pictures, the zoom property for android is working perfectly and is doing it's job, however on iOs it's not working as expected.

If you need more infos I am at your disposal. I would be very greatful to hear your opinions.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Ups, can this be the cause my zoom is messed up ?